# MongoDB replication: how to keep the possibility of writing to a replica set with a single "surviving" member

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

I have a MongoDB replica set of 3 machines. When two of them go down, the last one doesn't change its state to PRIMARY and it is not possible to write to database. Is it possible to make the last survivor a PRIMARY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to set the votes and eligibility of other members from becoming primary, this way MongoDB will only ever see one eligible member, however, in an automated manner the answer is no.

Once the majority of the set is offline MongoDB will, by default, halt writes and `primary` read preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an `arbiter` (see [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/)) to help with the election. Without having to maintain an extra mongod server.

Comment: Having two arbiters is not recommended. You should only add a single arbiter for election tie breaks

Comment: Your answer was right before you would need two arbs to garnish a majority, the problem is that it is not recommended is what orid was saying I believe